# Getting ElmahR to work with an persistence layer

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, signalr, elmah, elmahr

I am having a problem with ElmahR and setting the persistorType. Without setting the persistoryType elmah logs perfectly to elmahR and the errors are shown on the dashboard. The problem arise when i want to add the persistorType. When i add the persistortype as follows:

```xml
<elmahr persistorType="ElmahR.Persistence.EntityFramework.EF4.EntityFrameworkPersistor, ElmahR">
```

It gives me the following error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: s

[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: s]
   System.IO.StringReader..ctor(String s) +12159044
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Json.JsonSerializerExtensions.Parse(IJsonSerializer serializer, String json) +139
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubRequestParser.Parse(String data) +101
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.OnReceived(IRequest request, String connectionId, String data) +127
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.<>c__DisplayClassc.<ProcessRequest>b__7() +96
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.FromMethod(Func`1 func) +61

[AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.]
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +26
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.Infrastructure.ErrorState.Rethrow() +33
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallContextAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +155
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +34
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +129
```

Am using the following:

- MVC project
- SQL-Server
- Entity framework 4.3.1
- ElmahR.Persistence.EntityFramework.EF4

used nuget to install ElmahR.Persistence.EntityFramework.EF4

My connection string for the ErrorLogContext:

```xml
 <add name="ErrorLogContext" connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ElmahR;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

---------- Update

Step 1: create mvc 4 project.

Step 2: use nuget to install dashboard

Step 3: setup webconfig and link other project

Step 4: redirect homepage to go to the dashboard.cshtml

So far so good the dashboard gets the projects errors and shows them

Step 5: use nuget to install ElmahR.Persistence.EntityFramework.EF4

Step 6: create an empty db. And set the connection string as shown above

It still logs the errors on the dashboard but does not create a table in the DB and still uses the in memory. So on refresh i lose the data.

Step 7: add the persistorType tag in web config as shown above

Now i get the error i posted.

Any suggestions on what am doing wrong here?

Comment: Not easy to tell. Two questions: 1) which version of SignalR are you using? The error seems related to it, although I can't understand why you see it only when adding the persistence module. 2) Did you try by adding the Persistence module for EF4 but *without* specifying the persistorType? If you have just one persistence module it should not be necessary to name it explicitly.

Comment: on 1) i used nuget to get your elmahR.core 1.1.5.  so i would assume the lastest version you supported with that package. will check first thing tomorrow when i got the change to check. 
on 2) if i leave the persistorType it does not show the error, and the dashboard works perfectly. Problem with that is, that it uses the in memory. Since i lose the data the second i refresh. It also does not create the database, which if am correct should be created automaticly when you give it a clean database.

Comment: To be clear the project/dashboard works perfectly with the persistence data layer installed, aslong as i leave the persistorType it works, apart from it not generating a database and losing the data on refresh.

Comment: I'm confused, what is the error you described earlier if now you say it works fine (apart not writing to database)? In  any case double check whether in your bin folder you have all the persistence-related assemblies in place (the ones from the ElmahR.Persistence.* packages you picked). The question about SignalR was to make sure you did not upgrade it separately to 2.x given that unfortunately ElmahR is still on SignalR 1.x, and it came because the call stack you showed dies somewhere in SignalR...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Ill update my initial question with the steps i have done. Maybe that gives you a better view on what i did or did not do.

Comment: Thanks for updating it. I'd suggest we take it offline from here because it's looking more of a support issue, so I'd ask you to [open an issue in Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/wasp/elmahr/issues?status=new&status=open). When you are done I'll try to reproduce the issue as soon as I can (but it might take me a few days to have enough time...).